# How to store results from SQL query and use it?

Tags: python, sql, sqlcommand

I am trying to see whether the type is either a the letter "T" or between number 1-6 for the specific data entry found with name and password.

```
  sql = 'SELECT type FROM table name WHERE name = "{}" AND password = "{}"'.format(username, password)
```

and then in psedocode i need something like:

```
if type =< 5:
      int()
elif type = "T"
      string()
```

I am using python 2.7

Comment: @py_noob I am using mysql and I am trying to see if the type is less than or equal to the value 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full script that will query the mysql DB, and use your above-mentioned logic to print the values.  I've included the python code as well as the sample database code for this test case.  Let me know if you have any questions.

**Python**

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(user='username', passwd='password',
                                 host='localhost',
                                 database='database')

cursor = connection.cursor()

NAME = 'Person_A'
PASSWORD = 'Password_A'
query = ("SELECT * FROM My_TABLE WHERE NAME = '%(1)s' AND PASSWORD = '%(2)s';" % {"1" : NAME, "2" : PASSWORD})


cursor.execute(query)

for item in cursor:

    type = item[0]

    if type.isdigit():
        if int(type) <6:
            print('Type is a number less than 6')
        else:
            print('Type is a number but not less than 6')
    else:
        if type == 'T':
            print('Type is a string == T')
        else:
            print('Type is a string but not the letter T')
```

**MYSQL**

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (TYPE VARCHAR(255), NAME VARCHAR(255), PASSWORD VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('T','Person_A','Password_A'),('4','Person_A','Password_A'),('7','Person_B','Password_B'),('t','Person_C','Password_C');
```

Comment: Not quite, I can't call type = 'T' because it's part of an SQL table, that's why I'm trying to run the sql command.